# Levendberg-Marquard vs Port nls

Tags: r, nls

Im having some problems to understand why I'm getting an error *Convergence failure: false convergence (8)* when I run a non linear fitting using *nls* along with the *port* algorithm, which allows me to set boundaries. However, when I run the same analysis using Levendberg-Marquard with the *nlsLM* function from the *minpack.lm* package, I do not get any error. If I print the residual sum-of-squares values at each iteration for both algorithms, it seems like both algorithms tend to similar values, but only *Levendberg-Marquard* gets a result.

**Levendberg-Marquard**

```
It.    1, RSS =    1.76518, Par. =    1.61122    14.4293    7.32653
It.    2, RSS =    1.75735, Par. =    1.60297    14.4605    7.45013
It.    3, RSS =    1.75712, Par. =    1.61089    14.4533    7.44742
It.    4, RSS =    1.75712, Par. =    1.61089    14.4533    7.44742
```

**Port**

```
  0:     1.2593170:  2.00263  12.9104  6.07606
  1:    0.88258975:  1.61122  14.4293  7.32652
  2:    0.87860226:  1.61181  14.3285  7.37931
  3:    0.87859739:  1.61201  14.3436  7.38792
  4:    0.87859738:  1.61195  14.3436  7.38792
  5:    0.87859735:  1.61193  14.3436  7.38790
  6:    0.87859734:  1.61191  14.3436  7.38790
  7:    0.87859734:  1.61191  14.3436  7.38790
```

PD: Shouldn't the RSS values of both algorithms be the same (or very similar) at the first iteration in both algorithms?

Any kind of help would be extremely appreciated since I've been struggling with this problem for quite some time!

Kindly,

Juan

Comment: Maybe if you set `control = nls.control(warnOnly = TRUE)` you get also a result from `port`. `0.87859734 * 2 ~~ 1.75712`

Comment: Setting `warnOnly=TRUE` give a result, but it's stated in `?nls` that this results should not be considered for further analysis.

Comment: Maybe you can come to approximately the same minimum by different value combinations.

Comment: `nlsLM` might give you a result but that doesn't mean you have true convergence. I tend to be wary of `nlsLM` fits if I have convergence issues with `nls`. I'd be extra-careful.

Comment: That might be the reason why _Port_ does not get any result unless `warnOnly=TRUE` is set. Nevertheless it's quite frustrating to get an error without getting more specific details.

Comment: I don't see how the error could be more specific. The convergence check indicates false convergence. The software can't know why the algorithm doesn't converge.